# Android Socket server dataInputstream cant show again pass datas

Tags: android, sockets, textview, datainputstream

A few days ago has been asked this question once, but did not solve my problem
So I then again my question.
In the client part, I think it should be no problem,because the use of serial ports examination is normal

The following are part of the client

```
try {
                byte[] buf ={(byte) 0x80,
                             (byte) 0x70,
                             (byte) 0x60,
                             (byte) 0x50,
                             (byte) 0x40,
                             (byte) 0x30
                        };                                                          
                dataOutputStream.write(buf); //writeBytes(String str)   
                dataOutputStream.flush();               
            }catch(Exception obj){

            }
```

The problem is SERVER,
I really can receive data, but only display the first set of data, there is no way to display the second set of data.

Even if I send out a second set of data, still show only the first set of data

The following are part of the servers(revised!)

```
private Runnable socket_server = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                test.setText("Listening...." + getMyIp());
            }
        });
        try{
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    test.setText("Connected.");
                }
            });
            try {
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());                    
                    do{
                        byte[] re = new byte[6];
                        in.readFully(re);
                        short tmp[] = {(short) (0xff & re[0]),
                               (short) (0xff & re[1]),
                               (short) (0xff & re[2]),
                               (short) (0xff & re[3]),
                               (short) (0xff & re[4]),
                               (short) (0xff & re[5]),};
                        int ddata0,ddata1,ddata2,ddata3,ddata4,ddata5;                 
                         ddata0=tmp[0];
                         ddata1=tmp[1];
                         ddata2=tmp[2];
                         ddata3=tmp[3];
                         ddata4=tmp[4];
                         ddata5=tmp[5];                     
                         dd0=Integer.toHexString(ddata0);
                         dd1=Integer.toHexString(ddata1);
                         dd2=Integer.toHexString(ddata2);
                         dd3=Integer.toHexString(ddata3);
                         dd4=Integer.toHexString(ddata4);
                         dd5=Integer.toHexString(ddata5);
                         handler.post(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                test2.setText(dd0+dd1+dd2+dd3+dd4+dd5);
                             }
                         });
                    }while(in!=null);                    
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        test.setText("error");
                    }
                });
            }                   
        }catch(IOException e){
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    test.setText("socket failed");
                }
            });
        }           
}};
```

Comment: It is very clear that your server thread finishes after the server read six bytes from the inputstream. But you are not closing the socket then. You should don that too as otherwise you cannot restart the server on the same port.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions,I tried plus serverSocket.close (); but the problem still exists

Comment: Of course. Then who would read the second time?

Comment: Sorry, I could still dont understand the code
But my idea is that when I have a data come in, these actions will naturally be executed, and textview should automatically show a second set of data ....
So my idea is wrong ...

Comment: If your server thread has finished new data can not come in. So how would that work?

Comment: I understand, I think I need some time to study how to make my thread can be started again, and let the second set of data can then come in, quite appreciate your

Comment: You don't have to start that thread again.Don'let it finisjh. Just let it run. You only have to put that reading code in a loop. Thats adding three lines of code. So all code in this block: `if(in!=null){..........}`

Comment: Thats adding three lines of code. So all code in this block: `if(in!=null){do (your code)while (not stopped);}`

Comment: Really thank you very much, I tried to join the do-while, but the situation is still the same can not be changed

Comment: Please show the adapted code here too.

Comment: I found the original code I was wrong,But the problem is the same,Can you re-read it?

Comment: I tried to join the do-while, but did not solve
while(in!=null){  do( my code ) while(in!=null); }

Comment: Please adapt the code in your post. You need only one while statement.

Comment: okay I have modified

Comment: Neither of those `flush()` calls does anything unless there is an unstated `BufferedOutputStream` somewhere, and the first would be counterproductive in any configuration. You're ignoring the value returned by `read(),` but in any case you should be calling `readFully()` instead. `in` cannot possibly be null at the point you're testing it. You're only reading from the stream once, so of course you don't get the second set of data. But there *is* no second set if data, as you're only writing once. What is this question actually about?

Comment: to EJP:Sorry did not upload the full code
I have uploaded the full code

Comment: Well you're still not reading anything twice. You need to loop on `readFully()' and what follows until it throws `EOFexception.`

Comment: to EJP:I'm sorry I was a beginner, I'm trying to fix this problem

Comment: Don't apologize, that's what this site is for, to fix problems. The `read()` should be `readFully();` it shoudl be inside the while loop; the testing of `in` for null should be removed; and the loop termination condition should be catching an `EOFException.`

Comment: I can receive from the client to pass over every piece of byte,
But now discovered another problem,once I broke the connection, when I want to connect again, but can not, how can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

I see you use flush twice. Before you write bytes and after. Is it necessary for your operation try to put the thread to sleep for a second or 2 so you can get the whole stream. I suspect the byte process is a little slower than expected.

`dataOutputStream.write(buf);`

`Thread.sleep(1000);`

`dataOutputStream.flush();`

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions,But I have to use the onclick button to send,this will result in a slow my work
I tried but the problem still exists

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I also have these problems, it is important to close your socket in the correct line of your application thread or parts of the stream can definitely be lost. Hope you work it out. I feel your pain. Let me know when you solve it and how.

Comment: You're a good man,I hope I can let you know the good news as soon as possible.

Comment: It is never necessary to sleep in blocking mode network programming.

Comment: it is not necessary but its one of those things to try when having problems

Comment: Thank you two,I have succeeded to solve this problem.
Without your collective wisdom I might have bogged down in.

Comment: Post your answer and answer your question for the benefit of others who may face your problem

Comment: No it isn't. It is just literally a waste of time, and a side-track from actually solving the problem. Good networking code has no sleeps.